# CSS function "content" doesn't work when trying to add a text

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to add a text before another text with the CSS code "content"

That's why I added this CSS code to my website:

```
p.price:before {
    content: "ca. ";
}
```

But actually this doesn't work.

http://adventskalenderkaufen.de/produkt/foto-adventskalender-design-mit-schokolade/

Thank you in advance for any help.

Best regards
Benjamin

Comment: It's escaped when it finally renders: `p.price:before { content: &quot;ca. &quot;; }`

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7o3E.png save the file in utf8 format

Comment: Please read: [something on my website doesn't work, can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) and create a [mcve] in the question.  As it stands your [code works fine](http://jsfiddle.net/9bp2afLg/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, allow me to re-render your code. I believe you idea code is absolutely correct. It has nothing wrong with it.

```
p.price:before {
    content: "ca. ";
}
```

However, please correct me if I'm wrong, I assume that you type your code in some web text editor. That make the character `'` and `"` in code will be convert to something else (sth like this `&quot;`). Which causes your code become a bug and browser couldn't understand it.

Below is your original code that my browser fetched:

[The root of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WmWJI.png)

My solution is you modify your code file (which is css file) in a real IDE (such as Notepad++ or Visual Studio Code) and re-upload to the host. Don't use text editor in WordPress. You never know what will happening with it.

[Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qj07Z.png)

You can add style to the css file of template/theme.

Comment: Thank you so much! That was the problem! Works now!

Comment: If this is what you need, you might want to check `best solution` so other people won't waste their time to answer an answered topic.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you are putting before price, but you need to do like this on your css file:

```css
.price:before{
content: "ca.";
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PAjk3.png)

You can try to put this code to main css file.

I hope this will help!

Comment: Thank you so much! That was the problem! Works now!